# Getting keys and values of dictionary if key in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a dictionary names "ngrams_count". I want to find all keys in this dictionary that are in a list called "words_to_find". I would also like to return the values associated with those keys.

So far, this is what I'm working with

```
ideasrep = [key for key in words_to_find if key in ngrams_count]
```

That returns only the keys that are found in the word list.

I'm also looking for a way to return only the key/values pairs for which the value is greater than one. I've tried a similar technique as this:

```
[(key,values) for key, values in ngrams_count.items() if values > 1]
```

However, this only seems to work if I stay within the dictionary and I'm running out of ideas... Ideally, I'd like a way to do these two things simultaneously.

Comment: `ideasrep = [key for key in words_to_find if key in ngrams_count.get(key, 0) > 1]`? Or `ideasrep = [(key, ngrams_count[key]) for key in words_to_find if key in ngrams_count.get(key, 0) > 1]`? It's a little unclear whether you've got two separate questions, or are trying to somehow merge two things into one. You need to elaborate a bit, ideally in the form of as much of a [MCVE] as you can provide (example input values for the two collections, desired output, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your first version is almost right, you just need to add `ngrams_count[key]` to the result.

```
ideasrep = [(key, ngrams_count[key]) for key in words_to_find if key in ngrams_count]
```

Or you can use the second version, but change the condition to check if the key is in `words_to_find`.

```
[(key,values) for key, values in ngrams_count.items() if key in words_to_find]
```

If `words_to_find` is big, you should convert it to a `set` before the list comprehension to make the second version more efficient.

Comment: Note: The `set` conversion should be done *outside* the listcomp; inside it (in any code written in a natural way) you'd end up rebuilding the `set` over and over and losing any benefits of `set`.